# How to test a JAVA project with SonarQube in a Concourse pipeline?

Tags: java, continuous-integration, sonarqube, pipeline, concourse

I'm working on a concourse pipeline , and I want to test the code source with SonarQube.
the code for the SonarQube part on the pipeline is :

```
- name: sonar-runner
  source:
    repository: cathive/concourse-sonarqube-resource
    tag: latest
  type: docker-image
resources:
- name: sonar-scan
  source:
    host_url: <URL>
    login: <LOGIN>
  type: sonar-runner
Dans le job :
- get_params:
          quality_gate:
            ignore_errors: []
            ignore_warns: []
        params:
          additional_properties: null
          project_key: vertx-account-service
          project_path: vertx-account-service
          sources:
          - src/main
          tests:
          - src/test
        put: sonar-scan
```

When I execute this code I get this error :
**ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
org.sonar.java.AnalysisException: Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property**
The Jar file is saved on build/libs and the code source is on src/main.

```
build
|
|- libs
|
src
|
|- main
 |
 |- java
```

I even tried to put the path "build/libs" to provide the jar but our pipeline work perfectly but our project is empty on the SonarQube.
Does anyone have an idea , thank u

Comment: Hi, you would need to provide more info on your build configuration (for example pom.xml), but from your question it is not really clear what your are using (if anything).